# Django querying for objects with ManyToManyFields

Tags: python, sql, database, django

Here's the situation:

```
class Party:
    # Hosts of the party
    hosts = ManyToManyField("User")
```

I have a user `u`. I want to make a query for all the parties he's hosting. How do I do that?

```
Party.objects.filter(hosts__in=[u])
Party.objects.filter(hosts__contains=u)
```

neither of those work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
u.party_set.all()
```

Comment: 'User' object has no attribute 'party_set'

Comment: @Charles it should, see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) . If you've set a `related_name` you should use that instead. Its the cleanest way.

Comment: @Charles please note that your model should inherit django's base model i.e your class should be `class Party(models.Model):` , try that then syncdb.

Comment: Thanks, that worked; I had a related_name set. Also, I did inherit `models.Model` I just didn't write that in my example. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like `u.party_set.all()`, where party_set is a Party manager object just like `Party.objects` so you can also apply different filters on it..
You can dig things further [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)